Will red cedar bark grow back?
I have a question about a large red cedar tree that I have two of them actually a contractor doing some land leveling ran over the trunk and stripped some of the bark off for some reason this is something that is bothering me so much and I really want to know if the bark will grow back as it is not only an eyesore but I'm worried it might affect the tree health if anyone could please give any insight on how to make this not only look better but make sure that nothing bad happens to the tree itself?


Never heard of bark regrowing, but can you use a brown felt-tip pen to mask the horror from delicate eyes?

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news - Plant wounds don't heal and go away, they leave scars, and yes it can hurt the healt of the tree - and the bark will not grow back.  On the other hand, trees are reslliant, and if they are more-or-less roots protruding from the ground the plant can grow more and other roots to compensate.  (In a few cases, pruning roots can actually stimulate plant growth - so provided its not round the main trunk it might turn out to be a good thing in the long term)
